How should I calculate the TE and TM modes on an anisotropic/uniaxial slab waveguide?
I want to find the equations governing the TE and TM modes on the following three-layered slab waveguide:

I know how to use the Helmholtz equation and solve for the boundary conditions on normal isotropic waveguides, but I have no idea how to procceed when the permittivities are given by matrices. Any advice would help, thank you very much!

I don't know if this will fully answer your question, but as a suggestion, you may want to try to solve the problem component-wise assuming that the permittivity matrices are isotropic first (i.e. same value on each diagonal).
In other words, assume something like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
D_{x} \\
D_{y} \\
D_{z}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \epsilon  & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \epsilon \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
E_{x} \\
E_{y} \\
E_{z}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but keep each component separate in your calculations.  Once you have convinced yourself that you get the correct answer (which I believe you already know how to do), go back and make the matrices anisotropic and redo the calculations.  Since you have already seen how the process works component-wise in the isotropic case, this may help guide your calculations in the other case.
As another suggestion, you may want to consult a book like Born and Wolf Optics (https://archive.org/details/principlesofopti00born/mode/1up) Section 14, where they discuss electromagnetic solutions in anisotropic crystals.  This may be of some use as well.

Thank you very much! I will try to use this method.

In theory it is not uniaxial slab. Wide
isotropy is not good permittivity.
In helmholtz equations there is no good approach for matrices.
